# Problems writing output to file when print statement is fine

Tags: python, output, indentation

The output from my print statements outputs the correct lines of data, the output file however only contains the last lines for the 3 if statements. I have tried varying the identation but this seems to only affect the code negatively.

```
import sys
import tokenize

file = []

f = open('Database.txt') # Opening File

for line in f:
file.append(line) # Reading in File

f.close() # Closing File

f = open('output.txt', 'w')

for line in file: # Printing out File
#print line

    tokens = line.split() # splits lines along white-space (tokenise)
    #print tokens
    desired =  '{0:<5}'.format(tokens[0])
    #print desired
    lined = line.split('|') # lhs is original line       

    if 'Not present in Line' in line:
        line1 = desired + ':' + lined[1]
        #print line1

    if 'Not present in TV' in line:
        #print line
        line2 = desired + ' : ' + ' sticking ' + ' Returning ' + '\n'  
        #print line2

    if 'Not present in Line' not in line and 'Not present in TV' not in line:
        #print line
        line3 = desired + ':' + lined[1]
        #print line3

f.write(line1 + line2 + line3)

f.close()
```

Comment: You also need to indent line 9: `file.append(line)` or else it's not inside the `for` loop.

Answer (score 3):

You need to indent the line

```
f.write(line1 + line2 + line3)
```

to the same level as the `if` statements before. Currently, it's outside the `for` loop and is therefore executed only after that loop has ended.

Also, you may want to add a newline character after each line:

```
f.write(line1 + line2 + line3 + "\n")
```

As Jon Clements has noted correctly, you need to think about what should happen if not all three `if` conditions are met - in that case, `lineN` variables may be undefined or may still be defined with the value from the previous iteration. In fact, it's *impossible* for all three conditions to be met at the same time, so you'll always encounter a `NameError` during the very first iteration.

Only you can decide if it makes sense to set them to a default value at the start of the `for` loop or to do something else.

Comment: Might also be worth mentioning that `line1`, `line2` and `line3` will at some points not be defined causing a `NameError`, or otherwise potentially have values from *previous* lines which is probably not desirable.

Comment: Yes, when I indent to the if statements, line1 becomes NameError. How do I get around this? Thanks

Comment: @AmyRose: Well, one possibility would be (as I suggested in the last paragraph) to set all three to a default value, for example `line1 = line2 = line3 = ""` at the start of the `for` loop.